# How parse string into map,the string read from a file location using java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, bufferedreader, filereader

I want to read a file  from  my driver location and parse the file data into map,the file type text and contain data are given below

```
dhaka : 1 : jamalpur City : 2
khulna City : 3 : Bangladesh : 1
```

I am trying to solve this problem,but always unable.Please help me,
here is my code

```
Map < String, Integer > amap = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
try {
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\t.txt"));
    String ss = null;
    while ((ss = buf.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] pair = ss.split(":");
        for (int i = 0; i < pair.length; i += 2)
        amap.put(pair[i], Integer.parseInt(pair[1 + i]));
    }
    buf.close();
    for (Map.Entry em: amap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(" " + em.getKey() + " " + em.getValue());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace( );}
```

show `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` please solve this problem

Comment: What was wrong with the answers from your previous question?

Comment: sorry,your answer cann't fulfill my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space characters around the number caused a NumberFormatException, and there are space characters around city names so change this line

```
amap.put(pair[i], Integer.parseInt(pair[1 + i]));
```

to this

```
amap.put(pair[i].trim(), Integer.parseInt(pair[1 + i].trim()));
```

It's a really bad practice to leave catch blocks empty, it hides the problem (the NumberFormatException in this case).

Comment: show result java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException see my edit question

Comment: Only if you have least one line with invalid data, maybe last row contains a space character.

You can skip invalid lines:
while ((ss = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] pair = ss.split(":");
                if(pair.length!=4){
                    System.out.println("invalid number of tokens: "+pair.length);
                    continue;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < pair.length; i += 2)
                amap.put(pair[i].trim(), Integer.parseInt(pair[1 + i].trim()));
            }

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < pair.length; i += 2)
    amap.put(pair[i], Integer.parseInt(pair[1 + i]));
```

should be :

`EDIT` :

```
            for (int i = 0; i <pair.length; i +=2) {

                amap.put(pair[i].trim(), Integer.parseInt(pair[(1 + i)].trim()));
            }
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTE :**

if you see the elements are not ordered , it's because `HashMap` doesn't maintain an order, you should change to `Map<String, Integer> amap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();` to see the ordered version of your elements.

**MORE ADDITIONAL NOTE :**

It will also work where the number of pair of (`Key` & `Value`) is different on every line , like :

```
dhaka : 1 : jamalpur City : 2 : v : 5
khulna City : 3 : Bangladesh : 1 : w : 5
x : 5
y : 9 : m : 2
```

Comment: you are right in this case,but when 
one line..> dhaka : 1 : jamalpur City : 2 : Bangladesh : 1
next line..>khulna City : 3 that means even or odd number index,what will be occur

Comment: thank you so much dear altruist @fev ,i give you up vote

Comment: @SakibHasan, I'm really really sorry, the previous answer of mine is wrong , technically the way you iterate the array is correct , the problem lies on .trim() itself which should be called on  .pair[i+1] , see my last update.., everyone except me is correct check one of their answer..not mine :)

Comment: i have test ur previous code that was correct but now edited code does not show any result

Comment: @SakibHasan, it shows the result but if you see correctly not all elements will show up. :)

Comment: hmm not show all element,why but  edited code does not show anything

Comment: show result java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  see my edit question

Comment: @SakibHasan, how about changing to    `BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(
                                new FileInputStream("D:\\t.txt"), "UTF-8"));`, but don't forget `.trim()` on `pair[1+i]`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to add a reader as well this should solve your issue. This will only work though if there is no possibility for parts of the pairs being on separate lines.

```
Map < String, Integer > amap = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
try {
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\t.txt"));
    String ss = null;
    while ((ss = buf.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] ssPairs = ss.split(" : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < splt.length; i += 2) {
            amap.put(ssPairs[i], Integer.parseInt(ssPairs[i + 1]));
        }
    }
    buf.close();
    for (Map.Entry em: amap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(" " + em.getKey() + " " + em.getValue());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: sorry @austin wernli, show result java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException see my edit question

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what error you are getting but I expect you are seeing

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1"

Is that correct?

If so the answer is because splitting the String ss with

String[] pair = ss.split(":");

will result in

"dhaka ", " 1 ", " jamalpur City ", " 2"

Where as you want 
"dhaka", "1", "jamalpur City", "2"

Those extra spaces will prevent the Integers from parsing. I suggest splitting you string with 
String[] pair = ss.split(" : ");

Comment: show result java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces between the : and the values, which cause a NumberFormatException when you try to parse int.

A possible replacement is:

```
Map < String, Integer > amap = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
    try {
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\t.txt"));
        String ss = null;
        while ((ss = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] pair = ss.split(":");
            for (int i = 0; i < pair.length; i += 2)
            amap.put(pair[i], Integer.parseInt(pair[1 + i].replaceAll("\\s+","")));
        }
        buf.close();
        for (Map.Entry em: amap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(" " + em.getKey() + " " + em.getValue());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace( ); // shows a NumberFormatException
    }
```

bhspencer's answer works as well, using ss.split(" : ");

Also, always check your exception when you have issues with your program, they are usually really useful.

**Edit:** as pointed out by @austinwernli, replacing whitespaces in the whole line would also delete white spaces in multi world entry. Thus the replaceAll function should be applied to pair[i + 1] instead.

**Edit 2:** ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException comes from an odd number of value on a line like `dhaka : 1 : jamalpur City : 2 : v : 5 : s :`

A workaround could be to change the for loop with :

```
for (int i = 1; i < pair.length; i += 2) {
    amap.put(pair[i - 1], Integer.parseInt(pair[i].replaceAll("\\s+","")));
}
```

This way the last value is skipped on a list of odd size. I also changed replaceAll to trim as it suits the question better.

Comment: This would change all the multiple word keys into one name keys.. (`jamalpur City` would become `jamalpurCity`)

Comment: @austinwernli you are right indeed, in that case this should just be applied to the pair[i + 1] string. I will edit my answer,

Comment: show result java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: edit, found the exception: it comes when you have an odd number of value on a line... a possible workaround is to start your i at 1 in the loop, and then you access indexes i-1 and i... this way the lone value at the end is skipped. see my second edit.